# Question about using Material Design Component for Web (MDC Web) in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am currently using Angular 8 and I want to use material design. I found that there are different versions of material design libraries provided online. I am not sure which one I should use. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thank you.

1. [Angular material](https://github.com/angular/components)
2. [material design components for web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web)
3. [angular-mdc-web by trimox](https://github.com/trimox/angular-mdc-web)

I think 2nd library is directly from material design but 1st and 3rd are from third party. How do I integrate `material-components-web` with Angular 8? Do I need to wrap it? If so, how do I do it?

I prefer the 2nd one because it is not by third party and it is directly under material design.

Comment: The first option is not really third party, it is the Material implementation for Angular. You can read more about it here: https://material.angular.io/

Comment: Although the library is provided by google, `angular material` is not up to date with the most current `material design` spec. `mdc for web` has the latest spec.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/ is the official page to Angular Material. If you want to know the differences then please look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180498/material-components-for-the-web-vs-angular-material-2

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea of that post which is using whichever library helps me accomplish my goals in the best way possible. But that post is answered in 2016, it's a bit outdated. Is there any update of it? Overall, is angular-mdc-web is better or angular material is better? Which library does usually get updates first?